# Namespace vs Visibilty in ClassLoader subsystem

Tags: java

Java has 3 different types of loaders and hence it would be having 3 different namespaces. Classes present in one namespace cannot see the classes present in other namespace for security reasons. My application class loader will load my application classes and now if my class is using String class how the visibility is provided then since the String class is loaded by bootstrap loader.

Answer (score 0):

I believe a 'ChildClassLoader' will always check its 'ParentClassLoader' (the bootstrap ClassLoader in this case) if the specified class is already loaded. and therefore the 'String' class (in this case) would be the same in all 'ClassLoaders'.

A simple check would be to printout the 'hashcode' for that specific class for every 'ClassLoader', since it would be different for every 'ClassLoader' if the class object isn't shared through a 'ParentClassLoader'.